# Vertical space before horizontal line

Tags: spacing, environments, paragraphs

I have defined an `exercise` environment which ends with a horizontal rule. I want to have some vertical space between the end of the environment text and the rule.
When I try to insert that, the vertical space ends up **after** (below) the rule instead of **before** it.

I have tried both `\medskip` at the beginning of the HorzLine command, and `\vspace{5\bigskipamount}` before the `\HorzLine` at the `exercise` environment, and both don't work.

What's going on?

Here is some code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{orange}{rgb}{1,.549,0}

\newcommand{\HorzLine}{\medskip\noindent\textcolor{orange}{\rule{\textwidth}{5pt}}}

\newenvironment{exercise}
{\noindent\small\textbf{Exercise:}}
{\vspace{5\bigskipamount}\HorzLine}

\begin{document}
    \begin{exercise}
        \blindtext
    \end{exercise}
    \blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: Should the title instead be `Vertical before horizontal line`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\vspace` doesn't take effect until you are in vertical mode.  `\blindtext` probably doesn't end with `\par` or a blank line, so it's still in horizontal mode when the environment ends.  put `\par` at the beginning of the end code for the environment to force the vertical space above the rule:

```
{\par\nobreak\vspace{5\bigskipamount}\HorzLine}
```

EDIT: added `\nobreak` to prevent a page break just before the `\HorzLine`.

Answer (score 2):

Simply change `\vspace{5\bigskipamount}` to `\vskip5\bigskipamount` solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to leave some whitespace in your code between the `\vspace` and the `\HorzLine`:

```
\newenvironment{exercise}
{\noindent\small\textbf{Exercise:}}
{\vspace{5\bigskipamount}

\HorzLine}
```

[image]

The whitespace changes the mode TeX is in.